# Blocks and parameter retainment

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

What's the retain policy in arc on parameters passed into a queue?

You have the following:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
// Do some stuff here
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
   // If I use the dictionary parameter in the queue, what's the retain cycle on in it with arc? 
});
}
```

Comment: draw retain graph use pen and paper, then you know it have cycle or not. in this case, you are fine

Comment: While using block, block just copies all the above declarations inside the curley braces in which block exists..

Answer (score 0):

The block will retain all of the objects referenced in it but that shouldn't be a problem here as it is just a GCD block you are dispatching and not retaining yourself. There would be a retain cycle if this block was being retained by an object that is also referenced inside it which is not happening here as you are not retaining this block at all.